# Unable to call sencha touch function from appdelegate's handleOpenURL

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to call sencha touch function named handleOpenURL which was in maincontroller.js
from appdelegate.m in ios

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
    {
    NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"handleOpenURL(\"%@\");", url];

    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    return [super application:application handleOpenURL:url];
    }
```

but it is getting called

**MainController.js**

```
handleOpenURL: function(url)
{
    console.log(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue that i am facing by creating a global variable in sencha touch "MainController.js" and assign the current "this" to the global variable

ex: `var that = this;`

then access it from appdelegate's handleOpenURL method

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (!url)
        return NO;

    NSString* jsString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@
                           "setTimeout(function () { \n"
                           "that.handleOpenURL(\"%@\"); \n"
                           "},1000);", url.host];

    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString1];


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

url is not a string. try using [url absoluteString] instead of url in your jsString.

Comment: Thanks gro for your quick response... i some how managed to fix the issue and posted the answer, Thank you very much